# how to open new tab by overriding the already opened tab onclick of a button?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular

I am just trying to open new tab onclick of a button. on second click i want to open new tab by overriding the already existing tab which was opened on first click.

Comment: Can you provide the related code in your question?

Comment: Are you using material tabs?

Answer (score 0):

That is a rather difficult thing to do - you would need to disable clicking on the first page, and instead send a message to another window if open already, and make it reload. Could be possible in Chrome and some specific browsers. I'd just find another way.

If you want to do this, this is the way: https://davidwalsh.name/window-postmessage

Comment: how to send message to another window?

Comment: Added link. Window.postmessage